# How can I target each link and make it's content pop up in a modal window?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

So, I may have been better off trying this from a working method, but I decided to take it on myself - I'm using WordPress and am trying to develop a way for articles to pop up in a modal window on click. I got it to work, but I can't get it to work for each link on the page. Here's my code:

```
$('.article-link').click(function() {
$('#article-pop').addClass('article-show').removeClass('article-hide');
$('#article-pop').load('<?php the_permalink(); ?>');
});
```

And my HTML to go along with it:

```
<a href="#" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark" class="article-link"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

with the 'close' option elsewhere:

```
<a href="#" id="article-close">Close</a>
<script>
$('#article-close').click(function() {
$('#article-pop').removeClass('article-show').addClass('article-hide');
});
</script>
```

And for reference, my CSS:

```
#article-pop {
display:none;
position:absolute;
margin:20px auto;
padding:20px;
top:0;
max-width:600px;
background-color:white;
border-radius:7px;
box-shadow:0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.article-show {
display:block !important;
}

.article-hide {
display:none;
}

#article-close {
display:block;
z-index:10;
}
```

I've tried adding `.each` selectors in my jQuery, but it returns an error. Because there are several articles on the page, it only opens the first one instead of getting the permalink for each, as I would like.

I hope this makes sense - if not, I'll try and be more specific.

Comment: You are making a reference to the class `.article-link` (which is not unique) to the click event of any element of that class and you are loading exactly the same `.load('<?php the_permalink(); ?>')` link for every element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with wordpress but if the links are dynamically generated when the page loads, you click trigger in jQuery won't trigger because the dynamically generated link aren't loaded in the DOM.

```
$(document).on('click', '.article-link', function() {
```